# how to add a loading page before the page completly shows up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a  loading page before the main page that will show up when the loading is complete. Like something which animates till the page load is complete ?

Comment: It is called a splash screen...

Comment: Splash screen is in terms of mobile apps in web it called pre-loader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you add this element in your page

`<div id="loading">
     <img src="http://www.iceflowstudios.com/v3/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/LoadingCircle_firstani.gif"  />
     Loading...
</div>`

jQuery:

`$(window).load(function(){
   // PAGE IS FULLY LOADED

   // FADE OUT YOUR OVERLAYING DIV
   $('#loading').fadeOut();
});`

Comment: Thanks for your efforts!!